# How to obtain a justified paragraph with correct word-spacing in tabular environment?

Tags: tables, spacing, paragraphs, hyphenation, arrays

I'm trying to obtain a tabular with three columns of text vertically aligned on top (using array package and p{'width'}), but I can't figure how to obtain a regular spacing between words, like a justified paragraph with correct hyphenation of long words.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, onehalfspacing, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=30mm,left=30mm,right=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon}}
\setmainfont{pala.ttf}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{setspace}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}|}
\hline
But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. &No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. & Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure.  \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output with irregular spaces between words]

Thank you.

Comment: For narrow text it may be netter to use `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}`. You may also want to use `\RaggedRight` instead of `\raggedright`, this require the `ragged2e package.

Comment: With \raggedright it gives regular spaces between words, but I need to obtain a justyfied paragraph.

Comment: Then there is no way, not when the text width is so narrow.

Comment: The text you show has long sequences of unhyphenatable words such as `pain was born and I will give you a`  the only thing TeX can do to justify this is stretch the word space. I don't have that font, with the default `explain` on the first line hyphenates but there are still big gaps

Comment: justification in narrow columns nearly always gives dreadful spacing, whether or not it's in a tabular environment.  just look at the spacing between words on any normal newspaper column.  it's an impossible situation.

Answer (score 2):

You could load the packages `ragged2e` and `array`and test with something like `>{\RaggedRight\justifying}p{3cm}`. But the easiest solution is simply: `\usepackage{microtype}`.

---

Edit: Both solutions seem not to work with XETEX.

---

See this example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, onehalfspacing, 12pt, english]{article}

\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=30mm,left=30mm,right=30mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{babel, ragged2e, array}
\usepackage[factor=3500, stretch=40]{microtype}
% \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon}}
% \setmainfont{pala.ttf}
\usepackage{array}
% \usepackage{polyglossia}
% \setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage{setspace}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\RaggedRight\justifying}p{3cm}|>{\RaggedRight\justifying}p{3cm}|>{\RaggedRight\justifying}p{3cm}|}
\hline
But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing
pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete
account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great
explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. &No one
rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure,
but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally
encounter consequences that are extremely painful. & Nor again is
there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself,
because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in
which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure.\\  %\arraybackslash

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

renders as:

[image]

Hm, not very convincing, maybe one could play with local microtype values, but it is not really good.

Comment: Remember the `\arraybackslash`, your suggestion kills the *new row* meaning of ``\\`` in the last row.

Comment: The text remains the same with this method.

Comment: @Alessio Which method? microtype? Here microtype changes a lot, but I have to admit, I compile with pdflatex.

Comment: Neither \usepackage{microtype} nor >{\RaggedRight\justifying}p{3cm} changed the situation. I'm using xelatex.

Comment: @Alessio Then you are out of luck, sorry. Maybe you can change to LuaTeX? However, the microtype manual displays (p. 7) a poor support for XETEX.

Comment: Things don't change neither with pdflatex nor LuaTex... I must be really out of luck :)

Comment: @KeksDose I think you would get a (slightly) better result if you disabled protrusion. This is what is pushing the hyphens into the borders of the table. Protrusion is designed to make stuff 'look vertical' even though it is not but it assumes you are up against a blank margin. (I could be wrong - it might look worse. But that's what came to mind when I looked at it. FWIW.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to give up something, if you want to keep justification, and white space control, you need to give up something else. this gives up on the usual hyphenation rules:
There are still some gaps but try it with your final font choice, you can always add more hyphenation entries.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, onehalfspacing, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=25mm,bottom=30mm,left=30mm,right=30mm]{geometry}

%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX, NoCommon}}
%\setmainfont{pala.ttf}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}\setmainlanguage{english}

\lefthyphenmin1
\righthyphenmin1

\hyphenation{ mis-tak-en tea-ch-ings buil-der co-m-pl-ete
hu-m-an hap-pi-n-ess  av-oid-s en-c-oun-ter con-se-qu-en-ces
 ex-tr-eme-ly pain-ful a-nd pai-n pr-ai-s-ing
 pur-s-ues  be-c-au-se cir-cum-st-an-ces
pl-ea-s-ure  oc-c-ur  wh-ich t-oil 
cir-c-um-st-an-c-es h-im th-ere
}
\usepackage{setspace}

\showhyphens{
But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and
  praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and
  expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the
  master builder of human happiness}

\showhyphens{
No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but
because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter
consequences that are extremely painful
}

\showhyphens{
 Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of
 itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which
 toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*3{>{\spaceskip .3em plus .1em minus .15em
       \xspaceskip.4em  plus .1em minus .2em\relax
}p{3cm}|}}
  \hline
  But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and
  praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and
  expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the
  master-\hspace{0pt}builder of human happiness. & 

No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but
because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter
consequences that are extremely painful. & 

 Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of
 itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which
 toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure.  \\ 
  \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```